# Free software to publish tiles on Amazon S3?

Tags: tiles, software-recommendations, open-source-gis, free-software, amazon-s3

Does anyone know of free software that would allow me to publish tiles on Amazon S3? I know of Arc2Earth, but it is not free.

Comment: Firefox extension s3fox http://www.s3fox.net/

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created your tiles you can upload them to S3 using a program like the Cloudberry S3 Explorer or S3 browser:

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx
http://s3browser.com/download.aspx